# Boss just quit leaving behind a toxic workplace. How do I handle this?

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment

I have been at this healthcare company for 2 years now. The team consists of 4 professional staff reporting to a director. I have a total experience of about 20 years in this field.

The director and I didn't get along at first. She didn't like to address issues (such as giving me the number of PTO days at the beginning of the year and telling me how I could use them), and had one favorite in particular who seemed to know inside information. I just played along and did my job well because this is a really good job and a good company.

A new college graduate joined about a year ago. She kept making many mistakes that I kept fixing. When I tried telling her a couple of times what the issue was, she complained to the director I was being mean to her. The director's response to this was, "Well, she can't handle not being right, so don't tell her. Let me know when she makes mistakes and I will talk to her."

Since I didn't want to make more enemies, I didn't complain to the boss. I just fixed whatever I could and kept quiet.

Over the past one year, the girl kept putting people down. The boss tried putting her in place several times. The girl got close to the other girl who was the boss' favorite. The two have started bothering people together, especially me.

My relationship with the director improved a lot. She realized what was going on, and right then, she quit. Thus, I am left with these two coworkers who create a toxic environment and a third coworker who is afraid to speak up. A new director is going to be hired soon.

I have considered leaving because the place is so toxic. However, it seems silly to leave a good job over the nonsense of two people. My boss' boss is a financial guy who wouldn't have the patience or time to get into this issue, and rightfully so.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: I always give a bad situation 6 months to work itself out and then decide.   As long as the situation is tolerable and check clears the bank.

Comment: How is this a 'good job'?

Comment: Are you now in the position of seniority, which is why you are asking for advice on this? Not sure what has changed since your supervisor left.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What's changed is that the boss who used to be the "best friend" of one of the troublemakers isn't there any more. Unless the OP is making a long term career plan to become a saint, just let the two of them stew in their own juice. The new boss will find out soon enough how (in)effective they are. If *they* go whining to the new boss who then comes to the OP to find out what's up, *that's* the time to put the other side of the story, not before!

Comment: You were asked to not fix the girl's mistakes and you did. Consider that your director may have wanted ammunition against her (when she made mistakes) and you prevented that.

Comment: Can you give the actors in this question fake names? I think this would improve the question a lot, especially for non native readers.

Comment: The boss' favorite I will name Emma, the new girl's name will be Chris. Chris complains about everything (she supposedly does all the work, if she needs to take responsibility about something she messed up she says  that she is "targeted," gossips all the time, and keeps trying to stir the pot).  Emma, on the other hand has been with the company the longest and knows all the tricks, feeds Chris lines to argue back if she is challenged. The result of all of this is Chris following Emma around all day, repeats what Emma said, supports her in meetings (no matter what Emma said).

Comment: I am basically fighting the two of them, or fighting Emma through Chris. I do not have a seniority position, however have more experience than all of them together and since this is healthcare, I try to do the right thing. They are still trying to figure out basic concepts and when things come back wrong I am the one discovering them cause I know the background of it. When I try to approach it with "Hey, just so you know.." they get defensive and don't even realize what the big deal is. I am wondering what kind of caliber of people I am working with daily.

Answer (score 34):

First, stop fixing others' mistakes!  You are enabling the monstrous behavior, because she's come to expect you to get her out of messes she makes.  Once you do that, she'll have no choice but to direct any problems to the new boss.  The boss may then delegate to you to take authority.  Right now, you've taken it upon yourself with no authority, and it's dragged you down.  Don't repeat your past mistake.

Your co-worker will raise hell with your new approach but for results (and for the truth to come out) you'll have to stick to your guns. You won't have to tell the new boss a thing; he / she will see for himself.

Comment: If you fix her mistakes behind her back, it looks like she is a faultless worker (which she isn't) and you take too much time to do your job (because you waste time fixing her mistakes). Don't do that.

Comment: This probably doesn't apply here, but what if company can't afford to tolerate these mistakes until boss realises where the problem is? I have worked on a lot of projects where such approach would ruin the product and/or result in loss of client (luckily, I didn't have troublemaker for a colleague, so this question is purely hypothetical for me)

Comment: The company will have to 'eat' it.

Comment: Great advice, thank you! It is kind of hard to not fix a mistake that comes back and needs to be addressed; I would either need to tell the boss (a couple of times a week) or tell the girl to fix her own mistake, which she can't handle. I am a bit in a catch 22, therefore decided to just do it myself because I was sick of drama.

Comment: @Betty33 I've been in this pickle myself for just over a year now.  I have a peer who, when he would get assigned some work, would always turn my way and ask,"do you know how to...".  We both have "senior" titles.  I'd refer him to an online resource, and explain a little, and he'd just come right back time after time.  When I noticed the pattern, I started answering, "Google it." -- which is what I have to do myself.  Research is an unwritten part of our job description, and I can't be his crutch.

Comment: AGH!  What the heck?!  No, advising someone in the healthcare industry to "stop fixing others' mistakes!" is *TERRIBLE* advice!  I can understand needing to find a different way to handle this that doesn't enable them, but saying, "The company will have to 'eat' it" because you didn't fix a transcription error in medical data and it caused someone to die?

Comment: @Kevin she SHOULD stop fixing other's mistakes... but she should also raise it with the boss (as her ex-boss told her to do) so that the mistake doesn't go unnoticed...

Comment: No, she *shouldn't* stop fixing mistakes that could cost lives.  She *should* alter her approach so that it doesn't also enable the mistake-makers to keep making the same mistakes.  You can do the second without stopping the first.

Comment: If you fix a mistake that could have cost a live, you **immediately** notify your superiors **in writing** so they can prevent similar mistakes in the future!

If you just silently fix them, what will happen if you are sick for two weeks? People just die because no one knows about those mistakes?

Answer (score 8):

Wait until a few months after the new director takes charge.

As someone with your level of experience certainly knows, each person has a different management style. Let the new director settle down for a while. See if he deals with the situation differently, for example, by reprimanding the "troublemakers" or by resolving the underlying issues that lead them to creating nuisance.

Until then, keep away from their nuisance and keep the business moving along  (by fixing their mistakes, or whatever else that is needed). It sounds from your description that you can bear with doing this for a while. Make sure to give an objective report to your new boss about all the major "fixes" and incidents.

For completeness and clarity, let me also mention: do not complain to the new boss soon after he joins about the old issues. Your new boss doesn't know about the old baggage you are carrying so it makes you look like a whiner.

How long you wait depends on your patience. If you run out of patience before you see improvements, or if things get worse under the new boss, then start looking for other options.

Comment: When fixing their mistakes, document it. Make sure there is a record...

Comment: Thanks for your response, you have a good point. I was just going to plug along until the new boss settles in, try to not get distracted with the drama. I cannot tell you how difficult it is, given that this is becoming about self-respect when I have been put down so many times after working so hard. I do believe they are being threatened by me, hence all the manipulations.

Answer (score 5):

Uh, you've got a few different problems you're having to deal with at the moment:

- You've got a coworker making lots of mistakes.
- You've got a coworker that's causing interpersonal strife.
- You've got a coworker that you don't have a productive communication channel with.
- You've got a boss that you can't talk to (technically, your former boss' boss is now your boss, until he hires someone for the management level between the two of you.)
- You're in a situation where mistakes can cost lives.

So, you're absolutely right in fixing the mistakes.  **Please don't let someone "deal with it", where 'it' is the cost of making a life-changing or life-ending mistake.**

But that's where things start going wrong - what approach you're doing while you're fixing the mistake.  As you've been shown, talking with the people making the mistake isn't productive in this case.  Instead of improving and *not making the mistake again*, they're raising drama about the issue.  And one thing your situation should drill home: if you're not the person's boss, you can't force change in behavior.  This is where the boss is needed.

I can understand why you're reluctant to get the former boss' boss involved.  So here's what I'd recommend to try to solve as many of those problems as possible:

First up - email your boss' boss something like this:

> Tim,
>
> Hi - we've been having problems with repeated mistakes in our area. 
>   Our prior director asked me to inform them when there were mistakes
>   being made so they could try to figure out a better way of handling
>   it.  Is it okay if I CC you on the emails about these mistakes until
>   we get a director hired above us?  With the idea that you can copy
>   these over to the new director when they're hired?

... and assuming they're okay with this, every time you correct a mistake:

> To: Alice
>
> CC: Tim
>
> Alice, please make sure you double-check the dosing medication against
>   the chart.  The amount of meds forwarded in the pharmacy instructions
>   was only half the required dosage.

At this point, Alice is likely going to be angry.  Not only are you 'being mean', but you're cc'ing higher-ups while doing it.  But here are the things you need to keep in mind:

1. You haven't been able to have a productive avenue of communication
   with her verbally.  Simply talking about things with her is not an
   option for you - because it doesn't work.
2. You want to be as absolutely unemotional and professional as
   possible.  It's entirely possible Alice will send a Reply All trying
   to verbally blast you.  Don't reply.  Simply do your job, and send
   emails when needed about mistakes.
3. You're shooting for getting the mistakes to stop.  Maybe this alone
   will.  Maybe it'll take a new manager coming in, getting forwarded
   the emails, and having a talk with Alice.